# How to use my iPhone as a "security token" to easily log in/out of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, security, login, automatic-logon

I'd like to use my iPhone's bluetooth capability to automatically log me out of my Windows 7 computer when I leave the room.

Is there any Windows software that can do this?

Failing this, is there some contactless security token that I can carry in my pocket?

Comment: I know could just use Win-L to log out, but I'd prefer something thats more reliable than me.

Comment: How would the iPhone know if you left the room though?

Comment: @JFW You don't carry your <insert-manufacturer> phone whenever/wherever you go ?

Comment: Yes... But how would it know if you left the room or just merely walked around the room three times?

Comment: @JFW I'm glad that you're not in charge of anything :)

Comment: My apologies, but I was not aware that there were such technologies that allowed room-proximation detection that was available on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [BtProx](http://btprox.sourceforge.net/) as one option.

> It locks on one of your Bluetooth
>   devices which are paired to the the
>   machine. When you walk away from the
>   computer the device is disconnected
>   and the computer is locked after
>   timeout. It is possible to run a
>   single application together with the
>   lock.